Avoiding Overlapping Connected Nodes in a Graph
I am facing an algorithmic problem at work. The problem can be summarized as follows: given a sequence of mathematical objects (e.g., integer) and an operation for adjustment (e.g., addition), what is the optimal way to select elements for adjustment and to determine the quantities of change for these elements so that after modification, there are no two neighboring equal elements in the sequence. The algorithm has to go in parallel, so that the process cannot be sequential. I am thinking this might be some optimization problem, but do not know the formulation.

As requested, I am giving the background of the problem and mathematical formulation of it.
First of all, I work on OPC (optical proximity correction) in computational lithography. The governing equation is the maxwell equation, as it is about propagation of light. We are seeking the best boundary (mask) so that after propagation of light through the mask, the optical field matches the chip design provided by a customer (e.g., nvidia, amd, qualcomm, etc.)
Seeking the best boundary is an iterative process. Each time we need to adjust the geometry of the mask (a sequence of polygons) and execute optical simulation to compare the simulated result to customer design. What I am proposing here is only a tiny portion of the adjustment algorithm. The background is, after each adjustment, we need to check all vertices of the set of polygons one by one and ensure that no neighboring vertices overlap.
I am proposing the formulation of the problem using the framework of graphs. In general, the graph abstracts connection between vertices of polygons. Each node stands for a location and a unit vector for direction of movement, and nodes are connected if they are neighboring vertices by geometrical representation. I am seeking an algorithm after execution of which, the following statement holds: for any nodes $a$ and $b$, if $a$ and $b$ are connected, then the locations of $a$ and $b$ are not identical (or more precisely, not within a certain threshold). The cost is the sum of absolute values of shifts for all nodes, and I wish to minimize that.

For what it's worth, I upvoted the posted question because I consider it to be a high quality math problem, even though the question is asking for a programming algorithm.  That is, I regard the question as mathematical, because the request is for an algorithm.  Further, not only has the OP (i.e. original poster) provided motivation (i.e. context), it is very plausible to me that the OP is untrained in the pertinent math topics.  So, I feel that it is unreasonable to require that the OP discuss pertinent tools, discuss solving strategies, or show work.

Now I have updated the question with background and formulation. This is an industry problem with mathematical nature.
